# Will doing the advanced developer programming & essay exam still make sense?

Tags: certification

In April 2015, I enrolled for the Salesforce Certified Force.com Advanced Developer exam and successfully did the multiple choice exam. Since then, the actual scheduling of a programming assignment was postponed until September, and when that window opened, I missed my chance to participate. This weekend I received an e-mail telling me that a new window has opened up, and that I will be able to register for a programming assignment soon.

In the meanwhile, the whole certification plan of Salesforce has been restructured, rendering most (if not all) of the certificates deprecated and replaced with new ones. I do not want to spend time and effort into an assignment that will only result in a certificate that will be obsolete in a few months. I did already pay for it, on the other hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Advanced Developer certification won't be obsolete, even if it is replaced by the Platform Developer I & II certifications.

I've just completed the Adv. Dev. programming assignment & essay, and upon passing (fingers crossed) I'll be taking the Platform Developer II transition exam as per Option 1 of this graph:

[link](http://www.salesforce.com/campaigns/success-services/developer-certification-in-progress.jsp)

Alternatively you could take option 2. Transition to Platform Developer I, then complete the Platform Developer II assignment & essay (almost / exactly identical to the Adv. Dev. assignment right now I believe) and achieve the Platform Developer II certification that way.

Comment: I did the same thing, plus in the programming assignment requirements for the Advanced Developer, it's says it can be done by Advanced Developer candidates as well as Developer || candidates.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will just go ahead with Option 1. Let's hope I do get to do an assignment this time though.

Comment: Good luck! They seem quite committed to working through the backlog of developers waiting for assignments, so you should be successful before long.